# N Puzzle in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, tree, artificial-intelligence, breadth-first-search

I'm trying to build a solution to the N-Puzzle problem using breadth first search in Python.

My solution is adept at finding an answer if all of the numbers bar the zero are in order. e.g.

```
initial_state = [1,2,3,4,0,5,6,7,8]
```

or

```
initial_state = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,0,8]
```

but fails with

```
initial_state = [1,2,5,3,4,0,6,7,8]
```

Pleases find below my implementation. If someone could point out the flaw in my logic it'd much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

```
def right(state):
    items = list(state)

    i = items.index(0)

    n = int(math.sqrt(len(items)))

    if (i+1) % n != 0:
        del items[i]

        items.insert(i+1, 0)

        return tuple(items)
    else:
        pass


def left(state):
    items = list(state)

    i = items.index(0)

    n = int(math.sqrt(len(items)))

    if i % n != 0:

        del items[i]

        items.insert(i-1, 0)

        return tuple(items)
    else:
        pass


def up(state):
    items = list(state)

    i = items.index(0)

    n = int(math.sqrt(len(items)))

    if n**2 < i <= (n**2 - n):

        del items[i]

        items.insert(i+n, 0)

        return tuple(items)
    else:
        pass



def down(state):
    items = list(state)

    i = items.index(0)

    n = int(math.sqrt(len(items)))

    if i > n:

        del items[i]

        items.insert(i-n, 0)

        return tuple(items)
    else:
        pass


class Problem(object):

    def __init__(self, initial, goal=None):

        self.initial = initial
        self.goal = goal

        self.n = len(initial)

        self.size = int(math.sqrt(self.n))

        self.blank = self.initial.index(0)

        self.top_row = [i for i in range(self.n) if i < self.size]

        self.bottom_row = [i for i in range(self.n) if self.n - (self.size) <= i < self.n]

        self.left_column = [i for i in range(self.n) if i % self.size == 0]

        self.right_column = [i for i in range(self.n) if (i + 1) % self.size == 0]

    def actions(self):

        result_list = ["UP","DOWN","LEFT","RIGHT"]

        return result_list

    def result(self, state, action):

        if action == "RIGHT":
            return right(state)

        if action == "LEFT":
            return left(state)

        if action == "UP":
            return up(state)

        if action == "DOWN":
            return down(state)

    def goal_test(self, state):
        return state == self.goal

    def path_cost(self, c):

        return c + 1

class Node:

    def __init__(self, state, parent=None, action=None, path_cost=0):
    self.state = state
    self.parent = parent
    self.action = action
    self.path_cost = path_cost
    self.depth = 0
    if parent:
        self.depth = parent.depth + 1

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Node %s>" % (self.state,)

    def __lt__(self, node):
        return self.state < node.state

    def expand(self, problem):

        return [self.child_node(problem, action)
                for action in problem.actions() if self.child_node(problem,action) is not None]

    def child_node(self, problem, action):
        next = problem.result(self.state, action)
        if next:
            return Node(next, self, action,
                problem.path_cost(self.path_cost))
        else:
            pass

    def solution(self):

        return [node.action for node in self.path()[1:]]

    def path(self):

        node, path_back = self, []
        while node:
            path_back.append(node)
            node = node.parent
        return list(reversed(path_back))

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return isinstance(other, Node) and self.state == other.state

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.state)

def bfs(problem):
    node = Node(problem.initial)
    frontier = deque([node])
    explored = set()
    while frontier:
        node = frontier.pop()
        explored.add(node.state)

        if problem.goal_test(node.state):
            return node

        for child in node.expand(problem):
            if child.state not in explored and child not in frontier:
                frontier.append(child)
    return [child for child in explored]


p = Problem((1,2,5,3,4,0,6,7,8), (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8))
bfs(p)

#returns   

"""[(1, 2, 5, 3, 4, 0, 6, 7, 8),
    (1, 2, 0, 5, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8),
    (0, 1, 2, 5, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8),
    (1, 2, 5, 3, 0, 4, 6, 7, 8),
    (1, 2, 5, 0, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8),
    (1, 0, 2, 5, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8)]"""
```

Comment: It fails because you haven't defined `bfs`, `up`, `down`, `left`, `right` and possibly some other things.

Comment: sorry I missed out some of my code, will update now. @paul-hankin

Comment: How did you test `up`? Both `up` and `down` are incorrect I believe.

Answer (score 1):

If you process the neighbors (children) of a node (state) by moving the `space` in `UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT` order, the solution of an `8-puzzle` with `bfs` starting with the initial state `1,2,5,3,4,0,6,7,8` will be like the following (you can check out where it's differing with your solution):

```
path_to_goal: ['Up', 'Left', 'Left']
cost_of_path: 3
```

[image]

You may want to refer to this https://sandipanweb.wordpress.com/2017/03/16/using-uninformed-informed-search-algorithms-to-solve-8-puzzle-n-puzzle/?frame-nonce=9e97a821bc for more details.

Answer (score 0):

This condition in `up` is never true: `if n**2 < i <= (n**2 - n)`.
And this condition in `down` is off by one: `if i > n`.

Whether the rest of your code is correct or not is unclear, but you need to debug the fundamentals of your board representation and manipulation code first.

In your space-moving code, I personally would turn your index into an `x` and `y` coordinate:

```
x, y = i % n, i // n
```

Then you can test more naturally: `x>0` for left, `x<n-1` for right, `y<n-1` for up and `y>0` for down.